# Eclipse MinGW Binary Not Found

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, mingw

I am attempting to run a simple C project in Eclipse.

I have read through every single possible thread about setting up Eclipse and I thought I had everything correct.

I installed the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, installed MinGW, and MySys.

I have set my System Variables `Path` to `C:\MinGW\bin; C:\msys\1.0\bin` and I have also selected *PE Windows Parser* in the Eclipse preferences.

Finally, I set the *Environment Variable* to name PATH and value set to the Path variable in the checkbox select list.

Yet when I go to run my program I get the error

> Launch Failed: Binary not found.

Have I overlooked something? I have cleaned/rebuilt/restarted my computer to see if that would fix the issue, still no luck.

EDIT: When I look at

> Project >> Properties >> C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols >> Includes Tab

Nothing is listed, I'm wondering if this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you just have to install mingw to c:\mingw, then add c:\mingw\bin to Windows´s PATH variable. that´s all. no msys or fiddeling around in eclipse needed

In Eclipse just go to File->new->C Project, select Executable->Hello World ANSI C Project, and select MinGw GCC toolchain in right window. That project should build and run from within eclipse without problems

If "MinGw GCC" toolchain is not shown in the toolchain selection, just uncheck the checkbox "Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the plattform" to make it show up

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had installed Cygwin first and it left Window->Preferences->C/C++->Debug->Source Lookup Paths with settings mingw was confused by.  I clicked Restore Defaults on the Source Lookup Paths tab and everything started working properly.  I guess the toolchain isn't happy with both Cygwin and mingw installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me also, I installed MinGW on D:\MinGW (i dont like to install on C),
and created an eclipse C project "dummy" (Executable-Helloworld-MinGW).

Compilation went OK, no result, I even disabled my antivirus nothing helped, so I moved MinGW folder to C changed both Env PATH and user PATH with C:\MinGW\Bin and ...\msys\bin. Stil didnt help.

So I decided to make a new project (same settings) but with name "c_project", compiled and it worked.

Seems that I may had another "dummy" named project and my eclipse cached something in it.

Try to create a new random named project or even a whole you workspace. Hope it helped.

Comment: I take it back, i was my AVAST antivirus + Eclipse.
Right after compilation avast deletes the Binary and eclipse wont recompile (saying "Nothing changed on project") thus leaving you with no error and an execution error with missing Binary...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but i just had the same problem and nothing i found online would work.

I managed to fix it my changing the default builder from CDT Internal to GNU Make, by right clicking the project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Tool Chain Editor > Current builder > GNU Make Builder.

Answer (score 0):

project->properties->c/c++ build-> tool chain editor->current toolchain

was crossGCC then change it to

MinGWGCC->apply and close and run program.

I hope this solution will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I too faced with the same problem. Let me tell you what worked for me.

If you are running it for the first time after installing MinGW and Eclipse make sure that you restarted the system once. And check whether the MinGW paths are added to the system path variable.

Before running the program, build your project in 'Eclipse'. This can be done by clicking the 'Hammer' icon the toolbar or by Project >> Build Project. Now click the 'Run' button in the toolbar or click Ctrl+F11 or Run >> Run in the menu bar.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem every once in a while and it became really tiring checking the binary parser everytime. I know when you build the project you should have the binary and a debug folder with the executable file inside.

I realized that the C project won't build the binary and executable files when the C file name has capital letters. I just USE LOWER-CASE FOR THE C FILE NAME and I never had the problem again.