# C++ Launch Failed. Binary not Found

Tags: c++, eclipse

In Eclipse Luna I'm getting a "Launch failed. Binary not found" error. This is with just their basic HelloWorld program that will be already written. I tried creating it with the MinGW C++ toolchain, and I ctrl + b'd before running it, and it still occurs. I also have selected the PE Microsoft Parser in the 'environment' subsection under Build. I'm also using Windows 7 64 bit. I still can't find a way to fix it, any solutions that differ from the one's that I've tried would be great, thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Are you getting an executable that you can launch manually from windows explorer?

Comment: I'm not getting an exe, and it's just the default HelloWorld that Eclipse pre-writes for you: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
 return 0;
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse MinGW Binary Not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686064/eclipse-mingw-binary-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

If the binary was not found, It is possible that the project did not build correctly or you never built it in the first place. If you built it and it gives you that error, try going to **Project** --> **Clean** and once you clean it click build once again and then try running it.